# Why plural form?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

I have started watching to the show Shtisel and I couldn’t help notice that sometimes the characters talk between them using the plural forms, even when directed to a single person.

For example, on the second episode season 1, Elisheva’s father opens the door and talks to Akiva in plural - "tazkiru li, mi atem?" or "tikansu, lama atem omdim achutza?".

I want to know why is that? Is this some new "fashion" in Modern Hebrew?

Answer (score 6):

It is the plural of respect. Think of Shalom Aleichem, which you say to an individual.

I will (now) add that this is a common feature of many languages. While not true for Biblical Hebrew (though there is the plural of mastery), looking at the entry on T-V distinction on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction):

> Yiddish makes use of the second person plural form as the polite form for both singular and plural. In the second person plural form איר (ir), there is therefore no distinction between formal and informal forms. There is a dialectal pronoun עץ (ets) strictly for informal second-person plural form, but this pronoun is rarely used today and is only found in some dialects of Poland and neighboring regions.
>
> Given that old German dialects were the main influence on the development of the Yiddish language, this form may be recognized with older polite forms of the German language.

So it might well be an influence of Yiddish, which indeed could exist more in more religious circles.

It *could* also be influence from Arabic:

> Modern Standard Arabic uses the majestic plural form of the second person (أنتم antum) in respectful address.[citation needed] It is restricted to highly formal contexts, generally relating to politics and government. However, several varieties of Arabic have a clearer T–V distinction. The most developed is in Egyptian Arabic, which uses حضرتك ḥaḍritak (literally, "Your Grace"), سعادتك sa‘adtak and سيادتك siyadtak (literally, "Your Lordship") as the "V" terms, depending on context, while أنت inta is the "T" term. Ḥaḍritak is the most usual "V" term, with sa‘adtak and siyadtak being reserved for situations where the addressee is of very high social standing (e.g. a high-ranking government official or a powerful businessman). Finally, the "V" term is used only with social superiors (including elders); unfamiliar people perceived to be of similar or lower social standing to the speaker are addressed with the T term inta.

Regarding Hebrew, they have this:

> In modern Hebrew, there is a T–V distinction used in a set of very formal occasions, for example, a lawyer addressing a judge, or when speaking to rabbis. The second person singular אַתָּה (ʔaˈta, masculine) or אַתְּ (ʔat, feminine) are the usual form of address in all other situations, e.g. when addressing ministers or members of the Knesset.
>
> The formal form of address when speaking to a person of higher authority is the third person singular using the person's title without the use of the pronoun. Thus, a rabbi could be asked: ?כְּבוֹד הָרַב יִרְצֶה לֶאֱכֹל (kəˈvod haˈʁav yiʁˈtse leʔeˈχol', "would the honorable rabbi like to eat?") or a judge told: כְּבוֹדוֹ דָּן בְּבַקָּשָׁתִי (kəvoˈdo dan bəvakaʃaˈti, "his honour is considering my request").
>
> Other persons of authority are normally addressed by their title only, rather than by name, using the second person singular. For example, officers and commanders in the army are addressed as הַמְּפַקֵּד (haməfaˈked, "the commander") by troops.
>
> In non-Hebrew-speaking Jewish culture, the second-person form of address is similarly avoided in cases of higher authority (e.g., a student in a yeshiva would be far more likely to say in a classroom discussion "yesterday the Rav told us..." than "yesterday you told us..."). However, this usage is limited to more conservative (i.e. Orthodox) circles.

Comment: Only in the late Acharonim do you find people say "Shalom Aleichem" to an individual. Classic sources have the grammar right. הגה: ורוקד ג' פעמים כנגדה ואומר כשם שאני רוקד כו' ואומר תפול עליהם וגו' ולמפרע כאבן ידמו כו' ג' פעמים ויאמר לחבירו ג' פעמים שלום עליך ומשיב הוי כשואל (טור).

Comment: @DoubleAA I am not sure I would agree that one has the grammar "right" and the other "wrong". Language, including Rabbinic Hebrew, develops over time.

Comment: @joshwaxman ko.; say you what ever;. any-thing gos. ?right? why talk even a bout grammar than.? sum sence their must bee of those wordz to alow a discussion, weather ontologically pro-found or knot. ewe not like wordz "right" && "wrong", but I'm not wrong for using them.

Comment: @DoubleAA The grammar of Mishnaic Hebrew differs from that of Biblical Hebrew, which differs from Modern Hebrew. When a *whole bunch* of people agree upon the contours of a language, then it can be described by *a* grammar. Here, a "right" Rabbinic Hebrew grammar employs the plural of respect, just as Yiddish and Arabic do. -- writing this as someone who has implemented various grammars.

Comment: otherwise, I could say that when you wrote "say **you**", you were wrong, because real English, that is, Early Modern English, only used ye (with a y) for plural and thou (with th) for singular. Yet here thou art, employing you for singular!

Comment: אין הכי נמי You actually can say that if you want. It's not offensive. Context, is what matters here. People break various grammar rules for various reasons all the time. No need to postmodern the meaning out of everything to avoid offending people. Do you suppose Kiddush Levana was composed in modern Hebrew? Did the Rama not speak Rabbinic Hebrew? Why do you assert that Shalom Aleichem is used for an individual? More likely is people didn't know grammar and coined a non-grammatical idiom (like 'oll korrekt') or b) something kabbalistic.

Comment: Notably, when even zero people agree on contours of a language it can be described by a grammar. Being describable isn't an interesting status.

Comment: @DoubleAA ok, let us consider what is more "likely". (A) that thousands of people were so ignorant of basic grammar that they made the jaw-droppingly stupid mistake of plural for singular, such that it became adopted. And that people were stupid in this way in both Hebrew and Arabic, where "salam alaikum", the plural is used to address the individual, and the response, wa-Alaikum-Salaam, parallel to Hebrew Aleichem Shalom, is the formal response.

Comment: or (B), in a formal greeting exchange, exactly where you would expect the plural of respect -- which is something that *exists* in languages -- both Hebrew and Arabic (or one influenced by the other), employ the plural even addressing an individual. But in general, this argument we are having matches other disagreements (in phonology, in tzniut), and is driven by similar ideological foundations...

Comment: Postmodernism vs Judaism? But you'd be surprised at how non grammatical things can catch on, especially as you say as a calque from another language (or form formalised liturgy, or from kabbalistic concerns). As I said above, right before using a made up verb, people break various grammar rules for various reasons all the time. It's not jaw dropping stupidity.